# is it possible to use in the same raspberry pi x10 heyu system and use it as a server to access from a app?

Tags: home-automation

is it possible to use in the same raspberry pi x10 heyus system and use it as a server?

Heyu web site: http://heyu.tanj.com/

The goal is to control a x10 house by a cm11 interface in a android or in a iphone.

Are there better solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal OS on the pi (GNU/Linux, in various flavours) is multi-tasking, so of course you can use it to do more than one thing at a time.

> The goal is to control a x10 house by a cm11 interface in a android or in a iphone.

Web interfaces are the easiest to develop, since you don't have to write much client code and existing webservers take care of much of the nitty gritty.  If you want to do something more custom, you'll have to write some kind of server on the pi and a full blown client app on the phone.